# Toggle collapse menu is not working and hiding the content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on this website - https://sampledemos.online/training/dashboard.html in which the toggle menu is hiding the content when menu expands.

```
<aside id="layout-menu" class="layout-menu menu-vertical menu bg-menu-theme active">
          <div class="app-brand demo">
            <a href="index.html" class="app-brand-link">
              <img class="logo" src="/training/images/weblogo.jpg">
            </a>

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="layout-menu-toggle menu-link text-large ms-auto">
                  <i class="bx bx-chevron-left bx-sm align-middle" onclick="openNav()"></i>
                </a>
          </div>

          <div class="menu-inner-shadow"></div>

          <ul class="menu-inner py-1">
            <!-- Dashboard -->
            <li class="menu-item active">
              <a href="course-master-list.html" class="menu-link">
                <i class="menu-icon tf-icons bx bxs-book-reader" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Course Master"></i>
                <div data-i18n="course">Course Master</div>
              </a>
            </li>
```

and am using javascript as below

```
<script>
function openNav() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#layout-menu').toggleClass('active');
        });
}
</script>
```

Below I have used styles like this...

````
#layout-menu.active {
    width: 64px;
}
.active~.layout-page {
    padding-left: 65px !important;
}
.app-brand .layout-menu-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.active .layout-menu-toggle {
    left: 4rem;
} 
```
Is there I missed anything in my codings...
````

Comment: You ask if there is something you missed? Is there an error you explained that I missed somewhere? I don't quite understand. It would be nice if you elaborated on the problem

Comment: Actually..No error...when I tried to expand the toggle menu my content is hiding behind the menu instead of showing the full content...

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to use toggle collapsible menu in my website, while doing so the content hide behinds the menu, when menu expands from collapse state.

Comment: You should edit your answer by showing what is wrong exactly with what happens right now and visualize how do you want your website to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then what's happening is that your plugin 'perfect scrollbar' is setting adding the class 'ps' to `<ul class="menu-inner py-1 ps">` which adds `overflow: hidden !important`. That means everything that falls outside that menu-inner container is hidden. If you check your element inspector and remove the overflow: hidden you'll see your toggle menu becomes visible.